# How to predict or simulate how google analytics is going to map page use?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I'm testing how different programmatic ways of updating the URL are tracked by google analytics (setting window.location properties, using the history API, etc.). I'm applying this to client-side routing and one-page apps.

One way to do the experiments is to create a google analytics account for each website I want to test, and then eventually go back and delete all of the unnecessary accounts.

I was wondering if there was a piece of software that would simulate how google does its tracking that I could run without the overhead of the google analytics system.